Overpass Turbo min/max coordinates
I can find examples for using Overpass min/max with tags in the evaluator, e.g.
area[name="Baden-Württemberg"];
node(area)[natural=peak](if:number(t["ele"])>1000);
node._(if:t["ele"]==max(t["ele"]));
out;

but I can't figure out the syntax to use lat and lon in the evaluator for the min/max.
Is it even possible?
The fundamental use case is that I'm trying to (best guess) correlate "entrance" nodes to a face of a building. Using building geometry you can figure out which direction an entrance is oriented, but this is isn't necessarily the "side" of the building in a human sense that the entrance is on (think of an exterior vestibule on the east face of a building; an entrance on the left side of this vestibule is "north-facing", which you can obtain from the building geometry, but you don't approach it from the north side of the building). The approach I'm considering is to create a bounding box with the min/max lon/lat from the closed way's node set, and use that with some heuristics to arrive at a best guess of which "side" of the building the entrance is on. In my parenthetical example above, you could calculate that while the entrance is north-facing, it's essentially adjacent to the east edge of the the building's "bounding box", so it's very likely to be on the east side of the building.
